# Terminal Closes On Running clear and large output commands

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash

When I run the `clear` command or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> or commands with large output like `ps aux`, my terminal closes. I have set the scrollback to unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be reading this thread and having the same issue, I have found a solution.

Turns out the problem was that my `/tmp` directory did not have the correct permissions. Only root had `rwx` perms and that caused my terminal to exit or crash whenever trying to issue a command that needed to access `/tmp` in some way.

To correct this, I `sudo su`'d into root user and issued `chmod 777 /tmp`. I logged out of root, closed terminal, reopened as normal user, and as is well.

How I discovered /tmp may be the cause: UbuntuForums

Comment: Where in Ubuntu Forums did you discover this? The permissions of /tmp should be `1777`, or `a=rwx,o+t`; the sticky bit should be set.